# Is there a mocha equivalent for rspec's `and_call_original`?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an old rails app using Test::Unit with mocha and I'm trying to test that an object receives a specific method call. I know that I can do that with mocha by saying:

```rb
object.expects(:method)
```

The problem is, I want the object to still execute the method I'm expecting it to receive. I know in rspec I was able to do this by saying:

```rb
expect(object).to receive(:method).and_call_original
```

Is there an equivalent for mocha?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is that it is not currently supported, although in November of 2019 the readme was updated to indicate that there's a possibility that it may be supported in the future:

[Mocha README changes](https://github.com/freerange/mocha/commit/10b8d9b27b3d320238bf74778e431100dbff2331)